# map function failing when scraping web links

Tags: r

I am trying to scrape some website links however I am running into an error: I have 10,000 links and when I run my code over the links I get this error:

```
Error: 'NA' does not exist in current working directory
```

I scale down the problem to try and find what causes the error and I apply the same code over 100 links and I get this error:

Error:

```
Error in doc_parse_raw(x, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html,  : 
  Excessive depth in document: 256 use XML_PARSE_HUGE option [1]
```

When I apply the code over a smaller sample of the links I get no error:

Code which works

```
sample_parsed_urls <- Map(parse_filing, head(test_urls_to_parse))
```

Code which doesn`t work (on 100 links):

```
library(edgarWebR)
test_parsed_files <- Map(parse_filing, test_urls_to_parse)
```

Two questions, can I use a `trycatch` function with `map` to skip over the links which give me an error?

Better yet how can I fix the issue and get all of the links. I have looked into using

```
test_parsed_files_purrr <- purrr::map(test_urls_to_parse, parse_filing)
```

which gives the same error:

```
Error in doc_parse_raw(x, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html,  : 
  Excessive depth in document: 256 use XML_PARSE_HUGE option [1]
```

(The code might take 5 minutes to run)

URLs which contain the error url:

```
test_urls_to_parse <- c("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/773468/000095014808000053/v38189e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/880116/000157104915001475/t81438_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1037646/000095015209001389/l35224ae10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1092367/000119312513403928/d540865d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1598665/000156459018005881/hrtg-10k_20171231.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1038363/000119312508034594/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/929987/000095013704001244/c83239e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/70858/000119312509041126/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1397516/000119312514080312/d634398d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1116463/000119312512114853/d279006d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1493491/000114036113012671/form10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1466301/000119312514076654/d668864d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1497316/000149731611000023/f10kjune302011version2.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/810029/000095014404002565/g87734e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/92230/000009223018000021/form10-k_4q17.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1113809/000095013706003138/c02747e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1034054/000091664102000492/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/89041/000114420409020795/v146328_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1044590/000104459013000015/in-2012x1231x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1548621/000154862117000009/npci-20161227x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1095315/000095013409006620/d67022e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1289636/000103883812000173/k033112.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/944075/000094407505000016/k10-2004_final.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1402436/000156459018003827/ssnc-10k_20171231.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1254595/000095012311024252/c13846e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/814585/000119312515073382/d868514d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1523404/000155837016003705/jpep-20151231x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1106851/000104746914005950/a2220474z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1368761/000139160910000065/f10_ksecurenetwerks.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1314052/000106299309000091/form10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/755003/000119312504088259/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1273441/000114420410010210/v175499_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1186362/000119312507071283/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/885307/000105291802000208/jc10kaug312002.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/8192/000162828019001107/exc-20181231x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/883984/000110465911008318/a11-2379_110k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/830052/000119312507054585/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/77360/000119312504035574/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/808326/000114036107020767/form10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/217346/000110465906011793/a06-1864_110k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1349437/000143774917005741/twer20161231_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1108185/000104746908002466/a2182798z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/8063/000089979704000097/form_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1017655/000114420415019424/v405023_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/879911/000114420412018030/v307134_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1098482/000119312505036268/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1346980/000119312511080561/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1358099/000108638010000016/ghk123109.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1364885/000095013409003379/d66269e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1321560/000095013307000960/w30493e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1353406/000116552714000255/g7386.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1043222/000119312512138460/d323973d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1333274/000119312513062873/d485991d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1387054/000121465913002027/c41213010k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1168213/000095012306004270/y19376e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/933974/000095013502005743/b44487bpe10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1294632/000095014406011647/g04573e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/857323/000095012306004899/y19841e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/92103/000082705216000222/eix-sce201510k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/15511/000001551111000006/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1285224/000104746912002671/a2208050z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1092699/000156459018003249/spsc-10k_20171231.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1410471/000141047115000025/ipc-12312014x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1333142/000095013408011028/d57515e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/797721/000095012311054646/a58662e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/20290/000110465903003198/j7246_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1069394/000135448813001671/fsi_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1076481/000119312506070581/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/95052/000119312513331010/d582050d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1090061/000093066103000520/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/944480/000094448009000011/form10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1222915/000119312504155510/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1036044/000089161803001451/f88746e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1093082/000095013709001527/c49692e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/720154/000092794605000008/bas10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1059784/000160706217000019/gnbt073116form10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1075607/000110465907016007/a07-6905_110k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1429560/000104746916010926/a2227657z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/776867/000104746908001968/a2182981z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/92472/000101706203000652/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/874710/000114420411055070/v235780_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/828678/000104746907005819/a2178728z10-k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1128928/000095014408001429/g11794e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1306035/000147793215002480/yusg_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/800457/000119312518077161/d475968d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/720154/000114420413069445/v363009_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1224133/000156459018005637/mchx-10k_20171231.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1252849/000119312508066465/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/723531/000095012311065947/l42678e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/805326/000119312514123197/d633862d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/797465/000095012310009169/c95712e10vk.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1069530/000119312504040443/d10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1451505/000145150512000030/form10_k2011.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1407463/000140746313000024/pse-20121231x10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1507615/000150761516000080/tllp10-k12312015.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1004740/000100474006000011/form10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1030469/000110465903021277/a03-3492_110k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1088120/000114420411015073/v214602_10k.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/353944/000035394403000040/k10igt2003.htm", 
"https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1526183/000149473312000192/f10kmay312012ahlrevised.htm"
)
```

EDIT: I suspect the error occurs due to a bad formatted htm table

Answer (score 1):

For this problem `purrr` has three useful functions that capture side effects. `safely()` and its two further sub functions `quietly()` and `possibly()` are adverbs and work just like `map()`. So in your case you could just replace `map()` with `safely()` if you want to return a list with `result` and respective `error` for each iteration. You can also use `possibly()` instead of `map()` - here you get a normal list like in `map()` but you can specify an output value that should be returned if an iteration throws an error.

Due to possible different errors I would suggest as a first step to use `safely()` to be sure if failing iterations all have the same error. Check out the documentation of `purrr::safely()`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, the following seems to output the links and reports the errors in a list `map(test_urls_to_parse, safely(parse_filing))`. It appears link 71 was giving the error.

Comment: Do you get the error in your complete sample (10,000) only once?